# add NSInteger to an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

Im loading my array in a `NSDocumentDirectory`:

```
self.images = [NSMutableArray new];  
for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
{ 
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"oneSlotImages%d.png", i]]; 
    NSLog(@"savedImagePath=%@",savedImagePath);
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath]]; 

        NSLog(@"file exists");
    } 
    NSLog(@"file does not exist");
} 

NSLog(@"Count : %d", [images count]);
```

Here is where I implement my array:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

    view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[images objectAtIndex:index]];
    return view;

}
```

I add the `NSInteger` with the array above in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
for (int x=0; x<+100;x++) {
        // add as NSString
        [images addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", x]];
        // add as NSNumber
        //[images addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x]];
}
```

I'm having trouble adding `NSInteger`. How to add `NSInteger` to an `NSMutableArray`?

Im having a crash:

> 012-06-04 16:25:19.064 Yens_PhotoSlot[7543:1a303] -[__NSCFNumber
>   size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9a49b20 2012-06-04
>   16:25:19.067 Yens_PhotoSlot[7543:1a303] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFNumber size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x9a49b20'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1ab6052 0x1e92d0a 0x1ab7ced 0x1a1cf00 0x1a1cce2 0x7dbc86 0x2bc4b 0xaadc 0xaefc 0xb6f7 0xf04f 0xa348 0xbddf
>   0x27cc7 0x7bafbf 0x7bb2d4 0x7bb5d7 0x7bb785 0x9d827c 0x797c92 0x7979a2
>   0x799a98 0x724499 0x724584 0x139ee00 0x199f4f0 0x19ed833 0x19ecdb4
>   0x19ecccb 0x32e1879 0x32e193e 0x6f3a9b 0x2efd 0x2e65 0x1) terminate
>   called throwing an exception

Comment: NSInteger is not a class
`typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;` 
see it is declared as. U should convert to some Class and class object can add to NSArray.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [NSNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
[yourMutableArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:yourIntValue]];
```

Comment: Please post the code where you add integer values to array.. Your code and your question doesn't seem to relate

Comment: adding part is not responsible for crash. you're calling [someIntValue size]; which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Umgre pointed out, nothing in your posted code that could cause the crash in the log..

Comment: so what should I use and where should I insert it.

Comment: If you are using xcode 4 and above, try to add an exception breakpoint. You might get the exact line where your code crash. Read under "Add Exception break point" in [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html) link

Comment: I guess your are calling "length" method in somewhere. so it doesn't crash with NSString but crash with NSNumber.

Comment: No I'm not calling it, I don't know why it crashes. It crashes on the `- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view` part

Comment: ah ok../ view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[images objectAtIndex:index]]; this part is wrong. Object in array is NSNumber, not UIImage. right?

Comment: its UIImage, but I want to assign an integer to it.

Comment: What do you mean assign an integer to UIimage?

Comment: Then you must somehow change the code to retrieve UIImage and NSNumber separately

Comment: you added NSNumber to array. so it can't be image.

Comment: I want to assign an integer to it. because Im comparing it to another integer.

Comment: Since you are using the same array to store UIImage's and NSIntegers (god knows why?) you must check whether the object retrieved using objectAtIndex: is an integer or image..

Comment: If so that I can't add NSInteger to it, how will I know the value of an array.

Comment: What do you mean by 'value of an array' ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying. please explain your strategy.

Comment: Please move extended discussions to [chat].

Comment: @Kobe.o4 the best thing you could do right now is to read NSArray and NSMutableArray documentation carefully and see what are the functions available to you. Also there is something terribly wrong in your logic to save UIImage and NSInteger in same array.

Answer (score 3):

Add `NSNumber`:

```
[images addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:someInt];
```

Answer (score 2):

**NSInteger** isn't an object -- it's simply typecast to int on 32-bit or long on 64-bit. Since **NSMutableArray** can only store objects, you need to wrap the integer into an object before you can store it.

Comment: how to wrap the integer into an object and then store it?

Comment: [yourMutableArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:yourIntValue]];